# Why is this XPath expression getting too much data?

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, xpath, xpathnodeiterator

I have a XPath expression that is supposed to return/get only one node out of the XML document. But it is getting more than the one. I don't understand why.

Code-behind:

```
Dim xmlNameTbl As XmlNameTable = rootDoc.NameTable
Dim xmlNS As XmlNamespaceManager = New XmlNamespaceManager(xmlNameTbl)
xmlNS.AddNamespace("asp", "http://test.com/asp")

Dim sectionPosition As String = rowNode.GetAttribute("ID")
'In this example sectionPosition is "A03"

Dim sectionLetter As String = rowNode.GetAttribute("ID").Substring(0, 1)
Dim sectionRowNumberText As String = rowNode.GetAttribute("ID").Remove(0, 1)
Dim sectionRowNumber As Integer
Integer.TryParse(sectionRowNumberText, sectionRowNumber)

Dim addingNav As XPathNavigator = rootDoc.CreateNavigator

Dim hello = rootDoc.ChildNodes

Dim addingItr As XPathNodeIterator = addingNav.Select("//asp:TableRow[@ID='" & sectionPosition & "']", xmlNS)
'Nodes with A03 and A02 are being returned, even though it should be only A03 returned
```

XML Document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root xmlns:asp="http://test.com/asp" xmlns:meta="http://test.com/meta" xmlns:cc1="http://test.com/cc1">
  <asp:TableRow ID="A03">
    <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:Localize ID="tagthreeCtrlNumberRes" meta:resourcekey="tagthreeCtrlNumberRes" runat="server" />
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:Localize ID="tagthreeCtrlDescRes" meta:resourcekey="tagthreeCtrlDescRes" runat="server" />
      <asp:Localize ID="tagthreeCtrlNoteRes" meta:resourcekey="tagthreeCtrlNoteRes" runat="server" />
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblthreeCtrlRes0" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" meta:resourcekey="rblthreeCtrl0Res0" Value="1" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="No" meta:resourcekey="rblthreeCtrl1Res0" Value="0" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="N/A" meta:resourcekey="rblthreeCtrl2Res0" Value="2" />
      </asp:RadioButtonList>
      <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblthreeCtrlRes1" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" meta:resourcekey="rblthreeCtrl0Res1" Value="1" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="No" meta:resourcekey="rblthreeCtrl1Res1" Value="0" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="N/A" meta:resourcekey="rblthreeCtrl2Res1" Value="2" />
      </asp:RadioButtonList>
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:Button ID="cmdthreeCtrlRes" meta:resourcekey="cmdthreeCtrlRes" runat="server" OnClick="FormDataSave_Click" />
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:Localize ID="lblAssmthreeCtrlRes" meta:resourcekey="lblAssmthreeCtrlRes" runat="server" />
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:Localize ID="lblQualthreeCtrlRes" meta:resourcekey="lblQualthreeCtrlRes" runat="server" />
      <asp:Button ID="cmdQualAcceptthreeCtrlRes" meta:resourcekey="cmdQualAcceptthreeCtrlRes" OnClick="cmdQualAccept_Click" runat="server" Text="Accept" Visible="True" />
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell />
    <asp:TableCell />
  </asp:TableRow>
  <asp:TableRow ID="A04">
    <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:Localize ID="tagoneCtrlNumberRes" meta:resourcekey="tagoneCtrlNumberRes" runat="server" />
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:Localize ID="tagoneCtrlDescRes" meta:resourcekey="tagoneCtrlDescRes" runat="server" />
      <asp:Localize ID="tagoneCtrlNoteRes" meta:resourcekey="tagoneCtrlNoteRes" runat="server" />
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:Localize ID="tagtxtoneCtrlRes0" meta:resourcekey="tagtxtoneCtrlRes0" runat="server" />
      <asp:Textbox ID="txtoneCtrlRes0" runat="server" />
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:Button ID="cmdoneCtrlRes" meta:resourcekey="cmdoneCtrlRes" runat="server" OnClick="FormDataSave_Click" />
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:Localize ID="lblAssmoneCtrlRes" meta:resourcekey="lblAssmoneCtrlRes" runat="server" />
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell />
    <asp:TableCell />
    <asp:TableCell />
  </asp:TableRow>
  <asp:TableRow ID="A02">
    <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:Localize ID="tagtwoCtrlNumberRes" meta:resourcekey="tagtwoCtrlNumberRes" runat="server" />
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:Localize ID="tagtwoCtrlDescRes" meta:resourcekey="tagtwoCtrlDescRes" runat="server" />
      <asp:Localize ID="tagtwoCtrlNoteRes" meta:resourcekey="tagtwoCtrlNoteRes" runat="server" />
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:Localize ID="tagtxttwoCtrlRes0" meta:resourcekey="tagtxttwoCtrlRes0" runat="server" />
      <asp:Textbox ID="txttwoCtrlRes0" runat="server" />
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:Button ID="cmdtwoCtrlRes" meta:resourcekey="cmdtwoCtrlRes" runat="server" OnClick="FormDataSave_Click" />
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:Localize ID="lblAssmtwoCtrlRes" meta:resourcekey="lblAssmtwoCtrlRes" runat="server" />
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell />
    <asp:TableCell />
    <asp:TableCell />
  </asp:TableRow>
</Root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot find anything wrong with the above code/XML.

Running your example works as expected, with `addingItr.Count` returning 1.

I double checked this by iterating the returned nodes like so:

```
For Each n As XPathNavigator In addingItr
    Dim nodeName As String = n.Name
Next
```

What code are you running to determine the count of the returned nodes?

**Edit**

From: [XPathNodeIterator Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathnodeiterator.aspx)

> An XPathNodeIterator object returned by the XPathNavigator class is
>   not positioned on the first node in a selected set of nodes. A call to
>   the MoveNext method of the XPathNodeIterator class must be made to
>   position the XPathNodeIterator object on the first node in the
>   selected set of nodes.

So what you are seeing when debugging is the InnerXml property of the root node.

Comment: During debug I hover over the addingItr variable and go through the properties. The property that I see this in is "InnerXML".

Comment: Seems you were right. I guess I checked the Iterator too early. Should have waited for it to MoveNext. Thanks, jdavies.